# fio on virtual disk created with dd to stress disk

Tags: linux, dd, stress-testing, virtual-disk

I am trying to create a script for my coworkers to use in the field that will stress the internal disks to a Linux server. I plan to put some logic in for finding the /dev/sd's available and such. But I wanted to put in a write test. I am aware that fio will blast away data existing on a /dev/ device and I don't want that. I was thinking I could instead create a file with dd and run fio against that file. Essentially it should still stress the drive and put it under load, but retain all the data.

I figure I would create a file the 90% of the size of the remaining space on the partition, so that I can hopefully cause more arm actuating while the disk is under stress.

## With this plan shouldn't destroy data on the disk correct?

basic commands I plan to run:

create 10 GB file

`dd if=/dev/zero of=myFileSystem.img bs=512 count=19531250`

start fio

`device=myFileSystem.img runtime=30 fio default.fio`

Comment: Why do you need to stress the drive?

Comment: And wouldn't a "proper" benchmarking tool such as Bonnie++  be more suitable?

Comment: you need to do the test inside your vm.

Comment: There is a lot of paperwork involved with getting Bonnie++ to be used in the field. fio is already approved and I have been instructed to use that.

Comment: I didn't realize fio already creates its own file if the --filename=/directory/file doesn't already exist. So the dd is not necessary. Although it was just as slow as dd to allocate large files, I imagine its writing to every block, where I would prefer it to create the file regardless of what data is already contained there.

Comment: It looks like fallocate may be what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Answer (score 0):

`# df -T
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2     ext3    30969600  23578008   5818428  81% /
devtmpfs  devtmpfs     3937216       180   3937036   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs     3937216         0   3937216   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc1     ext3   864658784  44030960 776705716   6% /mnt`

`# size=641168811k fioFilename=/mnt/diskStressTempFile.1427125883.52 runtime=28800 fio defaultFile.fio`

`# cat defaultFile.fio`

```
[global]
ioengine=libaio
direct=1
iodepth=64
rw=randread
time_based=1
runtime=${runtime}
filename=${fioFilename}
size=${size}

[default]
name=default
blocksize_range=1k-4M
```

It is really slow to create the file though. It is pretty much doing a `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/diskStressTempFile.1427125883.52`

[`fallocate` is a better way to create a large file if you don't care about the contents beforehand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system) Unfortunately it seems that isn't available on the OS I am working with.